# IllegalStateException("JsonReader is closed")

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

This code **doesn't** throw:

```
override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): List<MyObj> {
        val result = ArrayList<MyObj>()
        reader.beginObject()
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            result.add(MyObj(reader.nextName(), reader.nextString()))
        }
        reader.endObject()
        return result
}
```

But if I add `reader.close` before return, or use `reader.use { }`, it will and it's catched here:

```
private fun <T> networkTransform(): SingleTransformer<Response<T>, Response<T>> {
        return SingleTransformer {
            it.onErrorResumeNext { throwable -> ...}
            ...
```

So my question is, do we need to handle close()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't close a reader in a JsonAdapter itself, only the calling code  (I.e. whoever created the reader and called fromJson()) needs to handle it.